# NodeJs - ETAG not working as expected with node

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple node server which returns a json response to the frontend. The etag function is enabled as you can see in the picture. When a second request is made at the same url the status code remains 200. It should have been 304 "not modified". Why is that?

[image: nODE]

FE:

```
const baseAPI = axios.create({
  //withCredentials: true
});

baseAPI.get("http://localhost:4000/").then(res => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

BE:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ value: "Hello" });
});
```

Comment: You probably is not validating the ETag on server side, read more about on "Caching of unchanged resources" session https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag

Comment: This also can be interesting, implementation details to use ETags, if you need some explanation about, ask us :) https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-2.3

Comment: @andergtk The validation of Etag is done automatically from BE. If i change the res.json({ value: "Hello" }) to res.sendFile('file.js') then you will see that it returns a 304 not modified